# Ideal of the ring of upper triangular matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}: a,b,c\in \mathbb{R} \right\}$ be a ring under matrix addition and multiplication. Then the subset $P=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0& p\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}:p\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ is
>
> 1. not an ideal of $S$
> 2. an ideal but not a prime ideal of $S$
> 3. is a prime ideal but not a maximal ideal of $S$
> 4. is a maximal ideal of $S$.

It is obvious that $P$ is an ideal of $S$. So all we need to determine is whether it is prime ideal or maximal ideal of $S$. Now we see that-
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&a\end{bmatrix}\in P$$ but $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&a\end{bmatrix}\notin P$. Here I have a minor confusion. For and ideal to be a prime ideal, if $ab\in P$ then either $a$ or $b$ has to be in $P$. In this case, the above mentioned matrix is not in $P$, does it implies $P$ is not a prime ideal? Also I don't know how to show $P$ is maximal or not. So can anyone help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: You are using the wrong definition of "prime." In a noncommutative ring like this one, it means that for any two ideals $I,J$ with $IJ\subseteq P$, either $I\subseteq P$ or $J\subseteq P$. That these two matrices which aren't in $P$ multiply to something in $P$ is inconclusive. In the full ring of $2\times 2$ matrices, the zero ideal *is* prime, but there are nonzero things that multiply to zero, nevertheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fix of a horribly wrong first attempt - thanks to @rschwieb for notifying me.

We are taking the following definition of prime ideal in a possibly non-commutative ring.

> [The ideal $P$ of the ring $S$ is prime iff for each $x, y \in S$, if $x S y \subseteq P$, then either $x \in P$ or $y \in P$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_noncommutative_rings)

We have
$$
x = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \notin P \qquad y = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \notin P,
$$
but 
$$
x \begin{bmatrix}a&c\\0&b\end{bmatrix} y
=
\begin{bmatrix}0&c\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \in P
$$
for all $\begin{bmatrix}a&c\\0&b\end{bmatrix} \in S$.

Comment: @rschwieb, I have corrected, thanks.

Comment: looks good now!

Comment: @rschwieb, thank you once more.

Comment: ok so what is the problem with the usual definition of the prime ideal?

Comment: You could see [this discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_noncommutative_rings).

Answer (score 2):

$P$ is not a prime ideal. Consider for example the homomorphism of rings
$$
S\longrightarrow \mathbb R\times \mathbb R,\quad \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ 0 & d\end{bmatrix} \longmapsto (a,d),
$$
where the operations on $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ are componentwise. This homomorphism is clearly surjective with kernel $P$. Hence $S/P\cong \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$, which is not an integral domain. Therefore, $P$ is not a prime ideal (and in particular not maximal).

Comment: This is correct, and avoids the problem existing in the other answer, but it leaves a window for misinterpretation. $P$ can be prime without $S/P$ being a domain (although in this case since $S/P$ is commutative, the two are equivalent.)  You can close this window by rewording to "which is not a prime ring (a commutative prime ring is an integral domain, and it is not an integral domain.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for setting me straight! I was not aware that the definition of being prime is different in the non-commutative case.